# Parse.com prevent Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I would like to prevent the message "`Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)`" I don't want to resolve it, because I know what's going wrong, but I would like to put exception. If Query doesn't find anything... NSLog something. (instead of crash)

Here is my code :

```
PFQuery *requestsToCurrentUser = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
    [requestsToCurrentUser whereKey:@"to" equalTo:self.currentUser];
    [requestsToCurrentUser whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"pending"];
    [requestsToCurrentUser findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            //this property stores the data for the tableView
            self.friendRequests = objects;
            //reload the table
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        } else {

            //error occcurred

        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put this

```
if(!self.currentUser){
     // No value in self.currentUser
     return;
}
PFQuery *requestsToCurrentUser = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
[requestsToCurrentUser whereKey:@"to" equalTo:self.currentUser];
[requestsToCurrentUser whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"pending"];
[requestsToCurrentUser findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        //this property stores the data for the tableView
        self.friendRequests = objects;
        //reload the table
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } else {

        //error occcurred

    }
}];
```

Comment: PFUser *currentUser = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"];
    NSLog(@"Hello %@", currentUser); returns me my username ...

Comment: I guess, you are comparing pfuser with "to" colume ??

Comment: what did this "to" field contains "string" means username or what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76571/discussion-between-malav-soni-and-xcode-dev).